# Rearranging to find Vmax

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics

I have a solution to a problem on the mechanics of materials.

For the last step to find the deflection Vmax I am not sure how equation (15) was simplified to get the answer shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ v_{max} = \frac{1}{EI}\left[ \frac{1}{2} M_0 \langle 0.5 a\rangle^2
- \frac{1}{2} M_0 \langle -0.5 a\rangle^2 
- \frac{1}{2} M_0 a\langle 1.5 a\rangle 
\right]$$

$$ v_{max} = \frac{1}{EI}\left[ \frac{1}{2} M_0 \langle \frac{1}{2} a\rangle^2
- 0 
- \frac{1}{2} M_0 \langle a\frac{3}{2} a\rangle
\right]$$

$$ v_{max} = \frac{M_0}{2EI}\left[  \langle \frac{1}{2} a\rangle^2
- a \langle \frac{3}{2} a\rangle 
\right]$$

$$ v_{max} = \frac{M_0}{2EI}\left[  \frac{1}{4} a^2- \frac{3}{2} a^2 
\right]$$

$$ v_{max} = \frac{M_0}{2EI} \left[  \frac{1}{4} a^2- \frac{3}{2} a^2 \right]$$

$$ v_{max} = \frac{M_0}{2EI}a^2 \left[  \frac{1}{4} - \frac{6}{4} \right]$$

$$ v_{max} = \frac{M_0}{2EI}a^2 \left[  - \frac{5}{4} \right]$$
$$ v_{max} = - \frac{5}{4}\frac{M_0}{2EI}a^2 $$
$$ v_{max} = - \frac{5}{8}\frac{M_0}{EI}a^2 $$

Comment: Thank you :) making the decimals into fractions makes it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to review how the "Macaulay Method", or "Step Function", works. As in the note, that "-a" in the middle term is less than the given value (x=0), so the term drops out. And the result only consists of the first term and the third term.

Form od the Step Function:

[image]